# How do I add a shortcode to a WooCommerce product description in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add a shortcode to a WooCommerce product description in the edit product UI. Something like this:

```
[recent-posts posts="5"]
```

The shortcodes will vary from product to product so I don't think tweaking the function.php is a practical solution for me.

Comment: The `Product Short Description` or the main product editor?

Comment: @mikerojas The Product Short description is where I'm looking to place the shortcode

Comment: I just installed WooCommerce on a local install of WP all are up to date and I was able to place a shortcode in there and it rendered as expected.  Are you getting an error?

Comment: @mikerojas no error was displayed. The shortcode output doesn't appear. maybe it has something to do with the theme I'm using